# php create array from arrays where value is equal

Tags: php, arrays

I´m having following array (only part of original size):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => cloudy
            [table_source] => rush
            [area] => land
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => sunny
            [table_source] => rush
            [area] => land
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => rainy
            [table_source] => rush
            [area] => land
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => hi
            [table_source] => calm
            [area] => mountain
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => low
            [table_source] => calm
            [area] => mountain
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [select_name] => medium
            [table_source] => calm
            [area] => mountain
        )
```

How can I merge this array where area name is identical compared to other arrays, to get the only the select_names with keyname from [area]

Wanted result:

```
Array
(
    [land] => Array
        (
            [0] => cloudy
            [1] => sunny
            [2] => rainy
        )

    [mountain] => Array
        (
            [0] => hi
            [1] => low
            [2] => medium
        )

)
```

Find here my poor try:

```
$ar1 = array(array("select_name"=>"cloudy","table_source"=>"sunny","fachdaten_name"=>"rainy"));
$ar2 = array(array("select_name"=>"hi","table_source"=>"low","fachdaten_name"=>"medium"));

$good = array("select_name");


$ar1 = array_intersect($good, $ar1);
$ar2 = array_intersect($good, $ar2);

$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Thanks for help, t book

Comment: So you have many arrays, not only one like in your sample?

Comment: right, the number of arrays can vary (it´s a database output the more rows the more arrays)

Comment: Why then in your code your arrays have no `area` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the most elegant solution but you could do this

```
$aSelectNames = array();

//Loop through the first array
foreach($aSelect as $select){
    if(!isset($aSelectNames[$select['area']])) {
        $aSelectNames[$select['area']] = array();
    }

    //Avoid duplicates
    if(!in_array($select['select_name'], $aSelectNames[$select['area']])) {
         $aSelectNames[$select['area']][] = $select['select_name']
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Pattle, should the first foreach loop not be foreach($aSelectNames as $select)?

Comment: @tBook No, its should be whatever your first array is called `$aSelectNames` is the array you want to build up

Comment: Hi Pattle, thanks for your solution. It worked for me, but I prefered to change the sql query to solve the problem there with string_agg and union all.